# How can I tell premake to generate a Makefile that uses clang?

Tags: build, makefile, premake

I would like to build my application using clang when generating a Makefile (gmake toolchain).  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: premake 5 has the option: `--cc=VALUE`. It doesn't work for me though - I always get GCC.

Comment: I know this question is old enough, but would like to ask is that possible to let premake to build it with precisely clang++ instead of clang?

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I use, it works for me:

```
--  ugly hack to use clang
premake.gcc.cc  = 'clang'
premake.gcc.cxx = 'clang++'
```

Nothing else seemed to work at all.

Answer (score 4):

On premake5, use

```
#!/bin/bash
premake-5.0.0-alpha11-linux --file=PA7.lua --cc=clang --verbose gmake
```

`--cc=clang` is analogue of --platform option in premake4.

Answer (score 2):

I ultimately ended up doing what @Burton Samograd did: assign the CC environment variable. However, buried deep in the premake4 message boards they do have a way to [define a new platform](http://industriousone.com/topic/newplatform).

When using premake4, just invoke:

```
premake4 --platform=clang gmake
```

The only problem I've found with this is it didn't work as I expected. I'm giving my vote to Burton, but the information is here if you want it.

Comment: When I try this I just get: `Error: invalid value 'clang' for option 'platform'.`

Comment: This is now an error in premake 5: `Error: invalid option 'platform'`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can just set the CC varaible:

```
CC ?= /usr/bin/clang
```

in your premake file.  The ?= only sets it if you haven't set it in your environment.

Comment: The whole purpose of premake is to generate these files automatically. You should never, ever have to modify them.

Comment: /Users/cweber/temp/premake/premake4.lua:1: '=' expected near '?'

Answer (score 0):

If you have premake 5, you can set the `toolset` option to `clang`in your `premake5.lua`

`toolset "clang"`  in premake5.lua